# Referencing data from Duplicated Tags

Tags: xml, xslt

I would really appreciate assistance with my problem.

Please could you assist i have looked online for a work around or a similar example but could not find anything.

**I have received the following xml to import into our system :**

```
<Address addressOrg="Import">
<Name>Sams Shop</Name>
<AddressOrg>01 Red Road</AddressOrg>
<AddressOrg>Summer Town</AddressOrg>
<City></City>
<Province></Province>
<Postcode></Postcode>
<Country>
<CountryCode></CountryCode>
</Country>
<AccountNumber></AccountNumber>
</Address>
<Address addressOrg="Exporter">
<Name>PToms Shop</Name>
<AddressOrg>01 Blue Road</AddressOrg>
<AddressOrg>Snow Town</AddressOrg>
<City></City>
<Province></Province>
<Postcode></Postcode>
<Country>
<CountryCode></CountryCode>
</Country>
<AccountNumber></AccountNumber>
</Address>
```

**Im am trying to complete the xslt below:**

```
<OrgsAddressCollection>
          <OrganizationAddress>
            <AddressType>ConsigneeDeliveryAddress</AddressType>
            <Address1><xsl:value-of select="Address/AddressOrg"/></Address1>
            <Address2><xsl:value-of select="Address/AddressOrg"/></Address2>
            <CompanyName><xsl:value-of select="Address/Name"/>/CompanyName>
            <Fax />
            <OrganizationCode />
            <Phone />
          </OrganizationAddress>
          <OrganizationAddress>
            <AddressType>ConsignorDDeliveryAddress</AddressType>
            <Address1><xsl:value-of select="Address/AddressOrg"/></Address1>
            <Address2><xsl:value-of select="Address/AddressOrg"/></Address2>
            <CompanyName><xsl:value-of select="Address/Name"/></CompanyName>
            <Fax />
            <OrganizationCode />
            <Phone />
          </OrganizationAddress>
<OrgsAddressCollection>
```

The problem with the above is that because the tag names are the same the first
set of address data seems to be pulling through to the second address as well when i am referencing it using the above code.

**I would like the the above xslt to output the Transformed result below:**

```
<OrgsAddressCollection>
          <OrganizationAddress>
            <AddressType>ConsigneeDeliveryAddress</AddressType>
            <Address1>01 Red Road</Address1>
            <Address2>Summer Town</Address2>
            <CompanyName>Sams Shop</CompanyName>
            <Fax />
            <OrganizationCode />
            <Phone />
          </OrganizationAddress>
          <OrganizationAddress>
            <AddressType>ConsignorDDeliveryAddress</AddressType>
            <Address1>01 Blue ROad</Address1>
            <Address2>Snow Town</Address2>
            <CompanyName>Toms Shop</CompanyName>
            <Fax />
            <OrganizationCode />
            <Phone />
          </OrganizationAddress>
<OrgsAddressCollection>
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing `<xsl:value-of select="Address/AddressOrg" />` is only going to get the first `Address` element, and the first `AddressOrg` under that.

Perhaps you only will have two address in your case, but to avoid too much duplicate coding, and to make it more flexible, you can use `xsl:for-each` (or `xsl:apply-templates`) here

```
<xsl:for-each select="Address">
  <OrganizationAddress>
```

And, within that, you would get the two `AddressOrd` elements by specifying the position of the relevant ones in square brackets (Note within the `xsl:for-each` you are now positioned on and `Address` element)

```
<Address1><xsl:value-of select="AddressOrg[1]"/></Address1>
<Address2><xsl:value-of select="AddressOrg[2]"/></Address2>
```

To customise certain output tags depending on the input, you can also use `xsl:choose`.

Try this XSLT fragment

```
<OrgsAddressCollection>
  <xsl:for-each select="Address">
    <OrganizationAddress>
      <AddressType>
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@addressOrg = 'Import'">ConsigneeDeliveryAddress</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="@addressOrg = 'Exporter'">ConsignorDDeliveryAddress</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
      </AddressType>
      <Address1><xsl:value-of select="AddressOrg[1]"/></Address1>
      <Address2><xsl:value-of select="AddressOrg[2]"/></Address2>
      <CompanyName><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></CompanyName>
      <Fax />
      <OrganizationCode />
      <Phone />
    </OrganizationAddress>
  </xsl:for-each>
</OrgsAddressCollection>
```

Comment: Hi Everyone thank you for the solutions very much appreciated.The problem with the xslt fragment above is this only will give me the ConsigneeDeliveryAddress information but in need it to be able to loop and provide the CosignorDeliveryAddress as well.There are additional addresses as well with different tags that is required to be hard coded.

Comment: <OrganizationAddress>
            <AddressType>AgentAddress</AddressType>
            <Address1 />
            <Address2 />
            <AddressLocal />
            <AddressExternal />
            <City />
            <CompanyName />
            <Country>
              <Code />
              <Name />
            </Country>
            <Email />
          
            <OrganizationCode>AABBCCDD</OrganizationCode>
            <Phone />
            <Ports>
              <Code />
              <Name />
            </Ports>
      
          </OrganizationAddress>

Comment: You can use `<xsl:choose>` to customise the AddressType. I have amended the answer to show this.